# In reference to the previous one i asked that why doesn't compiler get confused on encountering same name for class and object?

Tags: java

Here the codes that are written are almost identical but the only change I made is that i replaced the name of object. But compilation of first is successful but in second it gives an error package n does not exist!!
Please explain this to me why?

```
//FIRST PART.
//this code runs and compiles successfully!! With output-> print2

class N
{

static class M
{
void print2()
{
System.out.print("print2");
}
}

static void print()
{System.out.print("print");}


public static void main(String args[])
{
N N= new N();
N.M m = new N.M();

m.print2();    
}
}
```

---

```
//this code has slight changes from the previous code. but fails to compile.
class N
{

static class M
{
void print2()
{
System.out.print("print2");
}

}

static void print()
{System.out.print("print");}

public static void main(String args[])
{
N n= new N();               //only this and next line are changed
n.M m = new N.M();    
m.print2();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
N.M m = new N.M();
```

is actually

```
MyClass.InnerClass innerInstance = new MyClass.InnerClass();
```

This is why people generally start class names with a capital and instance names with a lower case character...

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, when you write `N.M m = new N.M()`, `N` is actually referring to the class, not the object. From the Java documentation of [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)
:

> For example, to create an object for the static nested class, use this syntax:
>   OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
>        new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();

So, when you write `n.M m = new N.M();`, the JVM will think that you mean n is an outer **class** not an object of the outer class. But, since Java is case-sensitive, the JVM will think that class "n" does not exist, giving you some errors in your code.